# how to Encrypt/Decrypt our sqlite database in mosync

Tags: security, encryption, github, xor, mosync

I have done Encryption/Decryption using XOR function in mosync and it works nicely. But while using for Binary File (SQLite database) its shows error that file can't be open. Then I used fread function like C++ but it also does not work . I want to add file Encryption same as github project.